# 'Undefined' output when requiring modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

test.js

```
var foo = require('./foo');
var bar = require('./bar');
console.log(foo());
console.log(bar());
```

foo.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log('In foo.js');
};
```

bar.js

```
module.exports = function() {
    console.log('In bar.js');
};
```

After running test.js in NodeJS I get this:

```
 In foo.js
 undefined
 In bar.js
 undefined
```

Where do two 'undefined's come from?

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(foo());
console.log(bar());
```

Here foo() and bar() are not returning anything that is why it is logged as undefined.

Answer (score 3):

A function with no `return` statement will return `undefined`.

You are logging the return value of `foo()` and `bar()`, each of which has no `return` statement.

Comment: Some more explanation: The console log statement in foo and bar are encapsulated. That's how modules work. You don't share a magic, global "console" object through all your modules. You have to explicit return stuff to make it available to other modules.